# Iterate through the DOM and then concatenate the resulting text values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

this is probably not explained very well but please bear with me, I've also included a fiddle which will help explain what I'm trying to achieve.

so I've been working on a little web app that concatenates strings of text (taken from input boxes and drop down boxes). This is achieved by hitting a "generate" button, which in the background runs the functions to concatenate said strings. It was working fine but I have just recently introduced an "addRow" button, which using JQuery clones one of the forms and all its contents and then changes the id for each element in the row (by adding a 1, then 2, then 3, depending on the number of times the '+' button is clicked.

Once there is more than one row, how can I iterate through the function that concatenates the string for the row that is replicated? My code will probably explain this better:

JSFiddle [here][1]

UPDATE:

So I've amended my code to use classes for the inputs/text boxes and now just cloned the forms (as they have a unique ID). I'm having trouble iterating through each form instance to do "something" (i.e. concatenate the strings)!

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QSzsg/5/). The code to actually concatenate the strings is done, I just don't know how to use the `.each()` function in JQuery properly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i removed your inline click and focus handlers... we will bind them with jQuery instead. I also added a class to all the inputs you would call the focus and blur on called `inFieldLabel` to facilitate easy binding.

HTML

```
<div id="placement">
    <h3>Placement</h3>
    <form action="" id="placement-form" class="placement-form">
      <input type="text" class="site inFieldLabel" value="Site" title="Site" />
      <input type="text" class="placementdesc inFieldLabel" value="Placement description" title="Placement description" />
      <input type="text" class="placementtype inFieldLabel" value="Placement Type" title="Placement Type" />
      <input type="text" class="size inFieldLabel" value="Size" title="Size" />
      <input type="text" class="pricing inFieldLabel" value="Pricing" title="Pricing" />
      <select class="servetype" title="Serve Type">
        <option>STD – Standard trafficking type (ie, regular display banners)</option>
        <option>SSV – Site-served (no ad server tracking)</option>
        <option>PIX – Pixel</option>
        <option>CCD – Click command</option>
        <option>PCC – Pixel and Click command</option>
        <option>RMV – Rich Media Video</option>
        <option>RME – Rich Media Expand</option>
        <option>RMO – Rich Media Other</option>
      </select>
      <span class="placement_span"></span>
    </form>   
</div>
<input type="button" value="+" class="addRow" />
<input type="button" id="generate" value="Generate" />
```

So now we have the clickclear and clickrecall functions defined to use as hnadlers for binding. Not sure if you had it in your original code but i added a check to make sure it only recalls/clears if the values are the defaults (eg. the orig. label or an empty string).

The bulk of what ou were having trouble with is in the `generatePage` function.

JS

```
  var uniqueId = 1;
  var generatePage = function(evt){
    $('.placement-form').each(function(i, frm){
      frm = $(frm); // wrap in jQuery
      // i is the interation counter
      // frm is the form element
      var site, placement_desc, placementtype, size, pricing, servetype;    
      site = frm.find(".site").val();
      placement_desc = frm.find(".placementdesc").val();
      placementtype = frm.find(".placementtype").val();
      size = frm.find(".size").val();
      pricing = frm.find(".pricing").val();
      servetype = frm.find(".servetype").val();
      var content = '<br />'+site+'_'+placement_desc+'_'+placementtype+'_'+size+'_'+pricing+'_'+servetype;
      frm.find('.placement_span').html(content);
    });
  };

  var clickclear = function (evt){
    var ele = $(this);
    evt.preventDefault();

    if(ele.val() == ele.attr('title')){
      ele.val(''); // if the value is a "label" then clear it for the user
    }

    return false;
  };

  var clickrecall = function(evt) {
    var ele = $(this);
    evt.preventDefault();


    if(ele.val() == '') {
      // if the user hasnt entered any text then revert to the "label"
      ele.val(ele.attr('title'));
    }

    return false;
  };
  $('.placement-form .inFieldLabel').focus(clickclear).blur(clickrecall);

  $('.addRow').click(function() {
      var formCopy = $("#placement-form").clone(true);
      var formCopyId = 'placement-form'+uniqueId;
      formCopy.attr('id',formCopyId);
      $('#placement').append(formCopy);
      uniqueId++;
  });

  $('#generate').click(generatePage);
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/JUfgd/

However, im not sure why you are trying to combine these strings or why you are using multiple forms. I assume you need to submit all this data somewhere at some point and to do that it would make more sense to actually have a single form witht he elements having `name` attributes in array notation (eg. `name="site[0]"`) then when you submit you can loop through on the server side with everything grouped together. Of course that can be hard to deal with when cloning so an alternate approach would be to leave the actual inputs outside of the form, and then assemble the data with js, similar to how youre already doing - only it would make more sense to use JSON for this instead of your own custom string serialization. If you need more info on any of this post a new question.

---

Well what i would do is assing a unique id to the form or add a wrapper container to the form that has a unique id, then i would use classes instead of Id's for the inputs/controls. This way you can clone the form or its container and all the children then jsut change the one id on that top level element. Then you can use a selector like `$(yourUniqueId .theInputClass)` which makes it a lot easier to manage.

Then you can just iterate over each form... for eas i would probably add a class to the form too jsut in case there are other non related forms on the same page so it would be something like:

```
$('.placementForm').each(function(i, formEle){
   // do stuff to the form
});
```

Comment: This is true. But as I mentioned my JQuery skills are a little limited but this is still a very good idea. Thanks

Comment: +1 *really* good idea.  I saw that ugly id cloning but didn't address it.  This is the way to solve it

Comment: Actually you're right, this is an excellent idea. I would then as you mentioned just need to iterate through each form as opposed to each element! :D

Comment: Ok thanks for this. After much deliberation, @prodigitalson I've amended the code but can't get it to iterate. What am I doing wrong? I'm sure it has something to do with the .each() function

Comment: Wow, this is awesome thanks @prodigitalson. The reason that I was using multiple forms is because there are many of these "forms" but only certain ones need to have an "add row" button but thanks for the update. I've also noted the excellent way to revert forms back to their original label. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote to clone all your elements:

```
$('#' + formId).find('input,select').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + uniqueId);
});
```

is already in the right neighborhood.  Since you're using jQuery, why not do something like this to get a string with all the values of your inputs and selects:

```
var str = '';
$('#' + formId).find('input, select').each(function(){
     str += $(this).val();
});
```

And of course if you want to pick up inputs and selects anywhere on the page, instead of just that form, you could do this:

```
var str = '';
$('input, select').each(function(){
     str += $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this might work, however I have more than just this one form on the page. There are others, such as ones for; advertiser, campaign etc. So presumably this would also pick all of those up too?

Comment: @Kiz - no, this will only pick up elements in that form, but see my edit