# Can't get .each() to work in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730565/iterate-through-the-dom-and-then-concatenate-the-resulting-text-values).

I'm trying to iterate through a series of forms on a page and do some "things" with said forms, but I can't get it to work. Code is below:

HTML:

```
<div id="placement">
<h3>Placement</h3>
<form action="" id="placement-form">
  <input type="text" class="site" value="Site" title="Site" onfocus="clickclear(this, 'Site')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Site')" />
  <input type="text" class="placementdesc" value="Placement description" title="Placement description" onfocus="clickclear(this, 'Placement description')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Placement description')" />
  <input type="text" class="placementtype" value="Placement Type" title="Placement Type" onfocus="clickclear(this, 'Placement Type')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Placement Type')" />
  <input type="text" class="size" value="Size" title="Size" onfocus="clickclear(this, 'Size')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Size')" />
  <input type="text" class="pricing" value="Pricing" title="Pricing" onfocus="clickclear(this, 'Pricing')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Pricing')" />
  <select class="servetype" title="Serve Type">
    <option>STD – Standard trafficking type (ie, regular display banners)</option>
    <option>SSV – Site-served (no ad server tracking)</option>
    <option>PIX – Pixel</option>
    <option>CCD – Click command</option>
    <option>PCC – Pixel and Click command</option>
    <option>RMV – Rich Media Video</option>
    <option>RME – Rich Media Expand</option>
    <option>RMO – Rich Media Other</option>
  </select>
  <span id="placement_span"></span>
</form> 
<input type="button" value="+" class="addRow" />   
 </div>
```

jQuery (this is for the "addRow" button):

```
var uniqueId = 1;
$(function() {
$('.addRow').click(function() {
    var formCopy = $("#placement-form").clone();
    var formCopyId = 'placement-form' +uniqueId;
    formCopy.attr('id',formCopyId);
    $('#placement').append(formCopy);
    uniqueId++;
    });
});
```

Here's the script I'm trying to get to work:

```
function getPlacement() {
    $('.placement-form').each(function(){
        var site, placement_desc, placementtype, size, pricing, servetype;  
        site = document.getElementById("site").value;
        placement_desc = document.getElementById("placementdesc").value;
        placementtype = document.getElementById("placementtype").value;
        size = document.getElementById("size").value;
        pricing = document.getElementById("pricing").value;
        servetype = document.getElementById("servetype").value;
        document.getElementById("placement_span").innerHTML = '<br />'+site+'_'+placement_desc+'_'+placementtype+'_'+size+'_'+pricing+'_'+servetype;
        return false;
    });
}
```

My understanding of the .each() function is that it wil loop through the DOM for each instance of that form named "placement-form" and then run the next few statements. Is this incorrect? Would appreciate some help on this!

Comment: you have to use $('#placement-form').each()

Comment: @ocanal - only the original element has that id, the clones are given sequential numbers (`#placement-form1`, `#placement-form2` etc)

Comment: Just a tip: declare the variables before the .each() loop. `function getPlacement() { var site, placement_desc, placementtype, size, pricing, servetype;
$('.placement-form').each(function(){`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake you've made is that your selector in the `.each` command uses `.placement-form`  - which looks for any element with the *class* placement-form... you're creating elements with the *id* of placement-form(x).

I would suggest adding a class to each newly created form (as id's must be unique, but classes have no such requirement).

```
var formCopy = $("#placement-form").clone().addClass('placement-form');
```

or just make sure the original has this class:

```
<form action="" id="placement-form" class="placement-form">
```

Then your `.each` should work as-is.

Another option is to use the [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) but i'd consider this the worse option as it'll be slower:

```
$('[id^="placement-form"]').each(...)
```

The above looks for any element where the id starts with `placement-form`.

---

Edit: Here's some pointers to getting your `getPlacement` function working

1) Change the span with the id `placement_span` to a class. You will end up with many of these and as previously pointed out id's must be unique. This will also aid you in finding the right one when looping over all `placement_form`'s

2) Remove the `return false`, as this stops the `.each` at the first matched form (meaning only the first one works)

3) Change `getPlacement` to use jQuery, especially providing the second parameter to the selector to narrow down the search to the current form. Here's some working code:

```
$('.placement-form').each(function(){
    var $form = $(this);
    var site, placement_desc, placementtype, size, pricing, servetype;  
    site =  $(".site",$form).val()
    placement_desc = $(".placementdesc",$form).val();
    placementtype = $(".placementtype",$form).val();
    size = $(".size",$form).val();
    pricing = $(".pricing",$form).val();
    servetype = $(".servetype",$form).val()
    $(".placement_span",$form).html('<br />'+site+'_'+placement_desc+'_'+placementtype+'_'+size+'_'+pricing+'_'+servetype);
    });
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/zu8ZJ/

Comment: Actually this doesn't throw ay JavaScript errors, but it also doesn't display any outputs, when I run the concatenate function :S

Comment: @Kiz - your `getPlacement` function has a number of errors, mainly that you're using `getElementById` but providing the class names of elements that repeat in every clone of your form. You should be using jQuery throughout. I'll update my answer shortly with more info if you need it!

Comment: thanks I've actually updated that after I realised on my machine. But still trying to debug and see what is happening. My jQuery skills are not as good as I want them to be!

Comment: would it be much easier for me to just use jQuery throughout? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
$('.placement-form').each(function(){
```

Will iterate over all elements with `class="placement-form"`. Therefore, in your code snippet you will never iterate over anything as there is nothing with a class name of "placement-form"

To iterate over elements within the form with the id "pagement-form", you could try something like

```
$("#placement-form *").each(function(){
```

Comment: I've tried this, as I want to iterate over forms that have "placement-form" in them but it doesn't seem to work - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
 $('.placement-form').each(function(){
```

you are selecting all the dom elements with the class name 'placement-form'

Try to add the class name to the form:

```
<h3>Placement</h3>
    <form action="" id="placement-form" class="placement-form">
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, it will loop through all entries with a class of placement-form. You need $('#placement-form') for it to use the id. But why are you usig each on a page with just one entry on - are you expecting to have multiple #placement-form elements?

Comment: He actually describes, both in text and code, cloning the original to make multiple copies of the form.

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat Yes, if you look at the code, I am cloning the form so the clones will have an ID of placement-form1, placement-form2 and so on

Comment: OK, in which case, the id won't work, and you will have to add a class as others have indicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.placement-form').each(function(){
```

You are using the class selector by looking for .placement-form, but in your function for adding a row it only sets the id attr. Maybe you can add the class in the addRow function and i think that should solve you're problem.

Check the [jquery documentation on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for reference.

Answer (score -2):

it should be

`$('.placement-form').each(function(){//etc etc})`

Comment: @Jamiec Actually that wasnt wrong.  He edited the question after i gave the answer.  He was looking for the class "placement-form" when the form had an id of "placement-form" instead.

Comment: @Richard - no, no he didnt (I can see the edit history). You just mis-understood what the problem was. But no bother it's answered now.